# SQL. Vista para consultar datos de varias tablas que empiezan por el mismo nombre

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, tablas, vistas, union

Voy a intentar explicar cual es mi problema...
Tengo una serie de tablas que se van creando cada mes con los nombres:
CONTROL_2023_1
CONTROL_2023_2
CONTROL_2023_3
.
.
.
Todas son iguales, es decir, tienen los mismos campos con los mismos nombres...

Lo que necesitaría es una vista para que me mostrara todos los registros de todas las tablas que en ese momento existan que empiecen con el nombre "CONTROL_".

Esta consulta me lo hace:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql+=N'SELECT * FROM '+QUOTENAME(name)+N';'
FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'CONTROL_%'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Pero al ir a crear la vista me da error en el DECLARE:
Incorrect syntax. '(', SELECT or WITH EXPECTED.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las vistas no pueden ejecutar código dinámico. Ni pueden ejecutar procedimientos almacenados, ni pueden cambiar la estructura de la base de datos. Eso solo lo puedes hacer desde un procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. El código que muestras no es el que daría como resultado una _vista_. Por lo mismo, no estoy seguro de qué es lo que realmente quieres lograr. Si es una vista en la base de datos, de las que se crean con `create view...`, o si es otra cosa a la que tú le llamas _vista_. Creo que sería bueno que [edit] tu pregunta e intentes explicarte mejor.

Comment: Te recomiendo crear una única tabla **CONTROL** con un campo **ANIO** y **MES**. Así es más fácil registrar y consultar datos y te evitas el crear tablas cada mes.

Answer (score 1):

El error viene porque estás terminando cada `SELECT` con un punto y coma (;) lo cual impide que se vuelva una sola instrucción para poder generar la vista. Eso sería más fácil de notar si usas `PRINT` antes de ejecutar tu código dinámico.

Otro punto a evitar, es el de usar el asterisco para crear vistas. Eso puede traer problemas en caso de que alguien cambie la estructura de una tabla.

Dejo el código de como lo generaría yo sin tener que copiar y pegar.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @sql += N'UNION ALL ' + CHAR(10)
      + N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME( o.name, '''') +  ' AS tabla ' + CHAR(10)
      + ( SELECT CHAR(9) + ',' + name + CHAR(10)
                FROM sys.columns c
                WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
     + N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME( o.name) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.objects o 
WHERE o.name LIKE 'CONTROL_%';
    
SET @sql = N'CREATE VIEW CONTROL_TODOS AS '+ STUFF( @sql, 1, 11, '') + ';';
PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT *
FROM CONTROL_TODOS;
```